How to fix 'This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
This is my query:
select 
  product_category,
  product_sub_category 
from prod_dimen 
where prod_id in 
(select prod_id 
 from market_fact_full 
 group by prod_id     
 order by count(prod_id) desc 
 limit 3
);

Upon executing this I am getting the error "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery"
I searched the internet for a solution but people just suggest rewritten versions of the query without using these keywords.Can anyone explain what actually causes the problem and how to fix it?

What version of MySQL are you using currently?

Try to use JOIN rather than IN

well if you don't have a certain feature then it's obvious that you cannot use the keywords associated with it. There's not so much to elaborate on in this regard. Like suggested, use joins, as for LIMIT, use SELECT TOP or ROWNUM.
